# Random walk based on coin toss

Tags: probability, self-study, random-walk

You are in an open field with two coins and you alternate flipping the coins and taking steps by the following rules:

```
If both coins are heads, then you take one step north.

If both coins are tails, then you take one step south.

If the first coin is heads and the second coin is tails, then you take one step west.

If the first coin is tails and the second coin is heads, then you take one step east.
```

Assuming that nothing is in your way and that the two coins are fair coins, then the probability that after 20 steps you are back to where you started is $\frac{p}{q}$ where **p** and **q** are relatively prime integers.

I want to find **p+q**.

Answer: I don't have any clue to solve this problem. If any member knows the correct answer to this question, may reply to this question.

Comment: Could you do this question if it was in 1 dimension rather than 2?

Comment: @Henry, I didn't understand what did you mean to say?

Comment: I mean if you only flip one coin and then use it to decide whether to move east or west, could you find the probability you are back at the start after $20$ steps? And so the corresponding $p+q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided on the other math website is as follows.

There are four outcomes of the tossings of the two fair coins, namely, $HH,HT, TH,TT$.

As there are 20 steps, the total numbers of outcomes will be $4^{20}=1099511627776$

Now the toss of first coin must be head to go one step north or west. And the toss of first coin must be tail to go one step south or east.

There must be an equal number of heads and tails on the toss of first coin. This gives us $\binom{20}{10}$ ways to flip the first coin and come again where you started.

Similar is the case for the flip of the second coin. Likewise, second flip must be head to go north or east. and second flip must be tail to go south or west. This gives $\binom{20}{10}$ ways to flip the second coin and go back to where you started.

So the probability of returning to start after 20 steps is $\frac{\binom{20}{10}^2}{4^{20}}=\frac{2133423721}{68719476736}$

So now **p=2133423721 and q=68719476736, so p+q=70852900457**